# Facebook opengraph (#2) Service temporarily unavailable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-opengraph, koala-gem

i have an app on which users post their shows. I want to add rsvp_events so that users can post their activity on facebook whenever they click on going button.
 I have setup everything, everything seems ok, but when i try to post the activity on facebook using **Koala** i get the following error,

```
"error": {
  "message": "(#2) Service temporarily unavailable",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "is_transient": true,
  "code": 2,
  "fbtrace_id": "H7WRzXo7d3C"
}
```

}

i am using koala gem and i am doing like this ,

```
@facebook = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
@facebook.put_connections("me", "namespace:go" , show: "http://samples.ogp.me/173451500015976867")
```

Any Solution?